# python add dictionary to existing dictionary

Tags: python

What am I doing wrong here? The append inside the dictionary doesn't seem to be working

```
final = []

topid = { 
    "ida" : "ida",
    "idb" : "idb",
    "idc" : "idc",
    "subid" : {}
}

for subid in subids:
    insubid = {
        "name" : subid.name, 
        "sida" : "sida",
        "sidb" : "sidb",
        "sidc" : "sidc",
    }
    topid["subid"].append(insubid)

final.append(topid)
```

I'm getting the error:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Are you looking for `dict.update()`?

Comment: You should also post the error message you get.  In this case, the error message actually says all you need to know.

Comment: @Sven "'dict' object has no attribute 'append'" is hardly "all you need to know"

Comment: show the error or result you get and what result would you like to produce

Comment: @ChrisMorgan The correct function to call is the other half. Yes, you can check the dict interface yourself and figure it out, but SO is for answering questions, not saying "check the interface yourself, you'll find it"

Comment: ah sorry the way the infrastructure was written I was getting a custom error returned I didn't realise it wasn't a django native error so it was't helping. I found out the actual error is AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: I don't understand the mindset of those willing to write a paragraph of bashing when the answer is just a couple words. You could have just pointed out the bug like Adam. Thank you

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: I think you are right, and my main point was that people should include the error message they get in their post.  I should have omitted the second sentence. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want, but by using `append`, your code is expecting `subid` to be a list.  If that's what you are going for, you should be able to change this:

```
topid = { 
    "ida" : "ida",
    "idb" : "idb",
    "idc" : "idc",
    "subid" : {}
}
```

to this:

```
topid = { 
    "ida" : "ida",
    "idb" : "idb",
    "idc" : "idc",
    "subid" : []
}
```

Notice that `subid` is now an empty list, instead of a dictionary.

Answer (score 7):

If I'm understanding this correctly, all you need to do is change:

```
topid["subid"].append(insubid)
```

to:

```
topid["subid"] = insubid
```